# Using global variables in python

Tags: python, c

I am new to python. I am trying to convert one of my c programs to corresponding python program, however I am not able to use global variable in python. My code in both c and python are :

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int globalcount;

void noofways(int firstnumchosen,int sum,int numofnum)
{
if(sum<0)
    return;

if(sum==0 && numofnum!=0)
    return;

if(sum==0 && numofnum==0){
    globalcount++;
    return;
}

if(numofnum<=0)
    return;

if(firstnumchosen>sum)
    return;

noofways(firstnumchosen+1,sum,numofnum);
noofways(firstnumchosen+1,sum-firstnumchosen,numofnum-1);
}

int main()
{
noofways(1,8,3);
printf("Required number: %d",globalcount);
return 0;
}
```

---

```
def noofways(firstnumchosen, sum, numofnum):
    global count
    count=0
    if sum<0:
        return 
    if sum==0 and not(numofnum==0):
        return
    if sum==0 and numofnum==0:
       count+=1
       return
    if numofnum<=0:
       return
    if firstnumchosen>sum:
       return
    noofways(firstnumchosen+1,sum,numofnum)
    noofways(firstnumchosen+1,sum-firstnumchosen,numofnum-1)

res=noofways(1,8,3);
print count
```

---

I think I know how to declare a global variable in python, but I am having problem in figuring out how to use that variable with recursion.

Comment: In what way is the code not working? It looks to me like it is printing 0, which is what I would expect it to do. Furthermore, why are you using a global variable with recursion? Why not just return the variable you're interested in?

Comment: move `count = 0` outside the function

Comment: I would note that Python and C are so different in terms of abstraction, trying to reimplement code from one language to another is a bad idea. The best thing is to ask yourself what the original was trying to do, then write it from scratch - that way you'll end up with Python that works in a Pythonic way, which will be far easier to read and maintain.

Comment: It should return 2. I need to increment the count once in a while (when i get the sum).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : Then the interpreter says "global name 'count' is not defined"

Comment: @CSSS: [it works](http://ideone.com/8ckpx) if you move `count` as I've suggested.

Comment: Seems like a bit of overkill with the `if` statements. You could probably condense it to 2 or 3 at the most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each recursive call will set the count back to 0

```
def noofways(firstnumchosen, sum, numofnum):
    global count
    # don't set count to 0 here
    if sum<0:
        return 
    if sum==0 and not(numofnum==0):
        return
    if sum==0 and numofnum==0:
       count+=1
       return
    if numofnum<=0:
       return
    if firstnumchosen>sum:
       return
    noofways(firstnumchosen+1,sum,numofnum)
    noofways(firstnumchosen+1,sum-firstnumchosen,numofnum-1)

# set count to 0 here
count = 0
res=noofways(1,8,3);
print count
```