# How to play a sound when a value increases by 1 between loops? What does the code look like that identifies the increment by 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, tkinter

I have designed and created a program using Python 3 that reads unread messages in my Gmail inbox under two labels.

By using tkinter I have two lovely boxes that display the total messages in each label. One for sales of one particular product and the other for another.

They use the **update** loop to recheck each label every few seconds. 
Then after the business day, I use a cleanup script in Gmail that flushes the inboxes two labels.

The program is for use on my team's sales floor. They can see daily, the number of sales, and get a real-time readout to the success of certain marketing campaigns. It has done wonders for morale.

Now I would like to implement some sounds when sales go up. A cliche bell ring, a "chhaaaching" perhaps, you get the drift.

So, I am currently tackling with my limited knowledge and have searched all throughout StackOverflow and other sites for an answer. My guess is that I need something like the following...

"if an integer value changes on the next loop from it's previous value, by an increment of 1 play soundA, or, play soundB if that value decreases by 1."

I can't for the life of me figure out what would be the term for 'increases by 1', I am also clueless on how to attach a sound to any changes made to the integer on the proceeding loop. Help!!

If I wasn't clear enough, I am more than happy to explain and go into this further.

Thank you so much guys.

Here is my code as it stands so far...

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import imaplib
import email
import tkinter as tk 

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 100


def update():
    mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
    mail.login('email@gmail.com','MyPassword')
    mail.select("Submissions")
    typ, messageIDs = mail.search(None, "UNSEEN")
    FirstDataSetSUBS = str(messageIDs[0], encoding='utf8')
    if FirstDataSetSUBS == '':
        info1['text'] = 'no submissions'
    else:
        SecondDataSetSUBS = FirstDataSetSUBS.split(" ")
        nosubs = len(SecondDataSetSUBS)
        nosubs = int(nosubs)
        info1['text'] = '{} submission[s]'.format(nosubs)
    subs.after(1000, update)

def update_2():
    mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
    mail.login('email@gmail.com','MyPassword')
    mail.select("Memberships")
    typ, messageIDs = mail.search(None, "UNSEEN")
    FirstDataSetMSGS = str(messageIDs[0], encoding='utf8')
    if FirstDataSetMSGS == '':
        info2['text'] = 'no memberships'
    else:
        SecondDataSetMSGS = FirstDataSetMSGS.split(" ")
        memberships = len(SecondDataSetMSGS)
        memberships = int(memberships)
        info2['text'] = '{} membership[s]'.format(memberships)
    membs.after(1000, update_2)

membs = tk.Tk()
subs = tk.Tk()

membs.title('memberships counter')
membs.configure(background="black")
subs.title('submissions counter')
subs.configure(background="black")

x = (subs.winfo_screenwidth()//5) - (WIDTH//5)
y = (subs.winfo_screenheight()//5) - (HEIGHT//5)
subs.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(WIDTH, HEIGHT, x, y))

info1 = tk.Label(subs, text='nothing to display', bg="black", fg="green", font="Lucida_Console 40")
info1.pack()

x = (membs.winfo_screenwidth()//2) - (WIDTH//2)
y = (membs.winfo_screenheight()//2) - (HEIGHT//2)
membs.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(WIDTH, HEIGHT, x, y))

info2 = tk.Label(membs, text='nothing to display', bg="black", fg="red", font="Lucida_Console 40")
info2.pack()

update()
update_2()
membs.mainloop
subs.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please narrow down your question. I'm sorry but we needn't the story for how this program affected sales department. Create a specific code for what you're asking instead using [mcve] guide.

Comment: Sorry about that Nae, I have actually noticed a better response when people get a bit of context. But of course I will stick to the rules in future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for playing audio you can use `pyaudio` module

in ubuntu, install by `pip3 install pyaudio` include sudo if required

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

increased=0 

inc_music=pygame.mixer.music
dec_music=pygame.mixer.music
inc_music.load("/home/pratik/Documents/pos.wav")
dec_music.load("/home/pratik/Documents/neg.wav")

def get_inc():
   global increased
   a=increased
   return a

def pl():
 global inc_music
 global dec_music
 while True:
  increased=get_inc()
  if increased == 1:
    inc_music.play()
    increased=increased-1
  elif increased == -1:
    dec_music.play()
    increased=increased+1
```

here `increased` is a global variable. Make sure whenever your sales is increased it is set to +1 and whenever it is decreased it is set to -1 and call `pl` function in a separate thread by using `threading` library in the background. Since, it is a forever loop it will continuosly run in background and ring the bells.

```
from threading import Thread

th=Thread(target=pl)
th.setDaemon(True)
th.start()
```

While writing the above I assumed at a moment there is either an increase or a decrease in sales, both dont occour simultaneously. If they do, use another global variable `decreased` which is also initialised with `0` and decreased by -1 each time decrease in sales. And return both of them from `get_inc()` .

Comment: Thank you for this Pratik. However, I am not sure how my 'nosubs' and 'memberships' integer values fit into your code. How would I link them into this? Are you saying that in your code, your global variable is replaced with these? If so how does my code actually look with this embedded? Also, the threading section you added is then to be positioned where? Sorry, I am a total noob here. Thanks again, I hope this isn't too much trouble to ask.

Comment: @Smokeyparkin assume that you have `check_increased()` function separately, which makes the global **integer** variable `increased` +1 if an increase in sales and -1 if a decrease in sales. position and start the threads before the `mainloop` of tkinter widgets, may be just after `update_2()` in your code

Comment: Cool, but how is Global linking into the code above? Is this just something is simply automatic and I just paste your code between my widgets and update_2()? Sorry, if I am being totally noobey here. Just want to make sure that I understand correctly.

Comment: @Smokeyparkin The code above is just for reference, an effort to express my idea for your problem. Simply copy-paste may not work, you have to customize it to fit into your code.  I suggest you do a little research on your side on how to work with global variables in python since talking about it would be out of the scope of this question. [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967645/using-global-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Below code produces a `label` that gets updated `random`ly, and plays the sound files located in `"C:\Windows\Media\"` based on the change:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from playsound import playsound


def sound(is_positive=True):
    if is_positive:
        playsound(r"C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav", False)
    else:
        playsound(r"C:\Windows\Media\chord.wav", False)


def random_update():
    _old = label['text']
    _new = random.randint(1, 100)

    if _new > _old:     # use (_new - _old) == 1 for checking
        sound()         # increment of 1 exclusively
    elif _new < _old:   # use (_new - _old) == -1 for checking
        sound(False)    # decrement of 1 exclusively

    label['text'] = _new
    label.after(2000, random_update)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root, text=1)

    label.after(2000, random_update)
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

[`playsound`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound) is not a built-in package so it needs to be installed separately. You can install using:

```
pip install playsound
```

or:

```
python -m pip install playsound
```

in the command prompt on windows.