# how to add sound to a message receiving function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently developing a Python-based chat program and I am trying to figure out how I would add a notification sound for when the user receives a message here's the message receive function for the client what i want to do is i wanna have a sound that will play when the user gets a message

```
def receive():
    """Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break
```

Comment: Paste some code with specific questions on problems you have. Linking your source code won't get any answer.

Comment: See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410073/7032856) I've written perhaps.

Comment: You seriously need some punctuations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first create a function to play a sound

```
import playsound

def play():
    ''' Setting second argument to False makes the function run asynchronously. '''
    isSync =  False

    playsound.playsound("/path/to/your/sound/file.mp3",isSync)

'''In your function to handle incoming messages'''
def receive():
"""Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
            play()
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break
```

Read more about `playsound` here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound/1.2.1\

Edit: Fixed indentation Error

P.S. : Thanks @Nae for suggesting improvement on async part.

Comment: marking the answer as expected (if it solved your purpose) will be appreciated.

Comment: This may block the GUI while the sound is being played, pass `False` as the second argument so that the sound is played _asynchronously_.